# create bitpay client in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I try to create a bitpay client in node after npm install bitpay and feeding it my on bitpay.com generated api key.

`var client = BitPay.createClient('apikey');`

I get:

```
assert.js:92  throw new assert.AssertionError({
AssertionError: Not enough entropy. Minimum is: 192 bits
at new HmacDRBG (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/node_modules/bitauth/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/hmac-drbg.js:24:3)
at EC.sign (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/node_modules/bitauth/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/index.js:94:14)
at Object.BitAuth.sign (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/node_modules/bitauth/lib/bitauth.js:101:25)
at RESTClient._sendRequest (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/lib/rest-client.js:156:46)
at RESTClient.get (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/lib/rest-client.js:282:28)
at RESTClient._getAccessTokens (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/lib/rest-client.js:81:19)
at new RESTClient (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/lib/rest-client.js:51:17)
at Object.module.exports.createClient (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/node_modules/bitpay/index.js:10:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/server/api/btc/btc.controller.js:6:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

if I try the website provided way:

```
$ npm install bitpay
var BitPay = require('bitpay');
var client = new BitPay('apikey');
client.on('ready', function() {
   client.post('invoices', { price: 10.00, currency: 'USD' });
});
```

it complains

```
var client = new BitPay('apikey'
TypeError: object is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/server/api/btc/btc.controller.js:6:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/enigma/WebstormProjects/expensereports/server/api/btc/index.js:4:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I also tried a couple of other ways non of them worked so my question how am I supposed to connect to this service?

If I use bitpay keygen to create a api.key file locally. How could I set this in my settings on bitpay.com to avoid {“error”: “Invalid token”}?

Answer (score 0):

There's a realistic possibility this API token is invalid. The 1st error message displayed means the API token's length is way too short and therefore invalid. Please verify you entered the correct API keys and enter it as a string. Are you sure you didn't remove the first character of the token when copying and pasting? Are you sure you didn't pick the wrong token? Example:

```
var client = new BitPay('MY_192_BIT_HUGE_API_TOKEN'); //192 bit string
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created a key and copy pasted the key from here:    https://bitpay.com/api-keys

Comment: However, creating a new instance with new BitPay() makes node complain that object is not a function. However BitPay.createClient() does exist and executes. iam very confused as there are so many different ways different sources claim how it should be done.

Comment: and indeed the key that gets generated on bitpay.com is not 192bit here is an example key from their website: wLePHyydbNXIJRs0sUY2RBK0WVV3GwYcVX7gN0vQGdY                            which is much shorter than the key bitpay keygen creates: 2CDsaSAeqE1kwnUrBpPTiwBkVf11c6G7eHs355QAvxQLVo581wBkGugnJse9Q4JTnamocD4ycxojhoyc6RGRwmzJpbxNUdng7n3HzPa17DnXdZ

Comment: so how could I make the locally generated key known to my bitpay account on bitpay.com?

Comment: Then use the 192-bit key